# Indesign images change size when "Publish online" is used

Tags: adobe-indesign, images

I have designed a booklet on InDesign, but when I publish it online, the image size changes on a few of the pages.

Here is the link to the booklet which has been published.

https://indd.adobe.com/view/73c43547-6995-4f60-821c-1cb463899213

On pages 4-10, the image is too small and leaves a white area. This is what the page looks like on InDesign before publishing:
[image]

Here's what it looks like when published online:
[image]

Can anyone explain why the image changes when published online and how I can fix this?

I've checked the layers and there aren't any other objects obstructing the image.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: The image isn’t changing size, it’s cropped. It looks from the screenshot like this is a two page spread and the image is stopping at the spine. Not sure how to fix it though. Maybe something spread related in your output settings?

Comment: All images after page 3 seem to crop to the spine this way. But Page 2 is fine. What's different about the image on page 2 compared to the image on page 3?

Comment: I bet that your image looks like it's part of each page but it's only on one page. Check your frames. You might need to duplicate it on the second page of the spread and set the frame accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help.

The issue was an overlap of an object with the image box on the master page. (I used the master page from page three onwards, which is why I didn't have the problem on the first couple of spreads)

The reason I didn't spot it was the fact it was on the master page and that the publish online feature made the object on top of the image box opaque, instead of 100% transparent (which it is in indesign and if you export to pdf).

Thanks,